# How to create android.jar OR where do i get it so that i can use all the componants of Android in Java Library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, temenos-quantum

I have created Java library in the Android Studio, but I am not able to use the Android Componanmts/frameworks in Java library.

Comment: Have you seen:https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library Java JARs have no concept of Android resources/assets.

Comment: The question has the tag, temenos-quantum. Are you trying to use the jar in Kony to integrate the Android component(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its available in the installed sdk path, Absolate path is **C:\Users\Arvind\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar** .

Where android-30 is the latest sdk version installed.